# Pass Kotlin Method to `javax.script.ScriptEngine`

Tags: java, kotlin, scriptengine

Recently I decided to get into Kotlin and wrote a toy application. I would like to extend my application with a Kotlin Scripting Interface.

From which I gathered, I need to use `javax.script.ScriptEngine`, which also seems to work. I am able to execute scripts like these:

```
robot.configure {
  name = "FrankaPanda"
}
```

Which works like a charm. However, I would like to refine my interface a bit further and omit the `configure` call. Basically, I want to achieve following script:

```
robot {
  name = "FrankaPanda"
}
```

To achieve this, I figured that "robot" needs to be a function, that accepts a lambda.
However, whenever I try to bind a method to ScriptEngine

```
val robot = Robot()
scriptEngine.put("robot", robot::configure)
```

the evaluation of my script fails with an exception:

> javax.script.ScriptException: Unresolved reference: robot

I tried several other approaches too, including `Consumer<Robot>` and etc. which all of them failed. However, I really want to omit the explicit call to configure and make my interface more "Gradle-esque".

**Question(s)**:

- How can I create a Gradle-esque scripting interface using Kotlin?
- (Bonus) How does Gradle turn arbitrary "extensions" into functions, that accept lambdas?

Comment: The answer depends entirely on what the scripting language is.

Comment: Sorry, my wording was a bit unclear. The Scripting Language of interest is Kotlin, too.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out to some part. I extended my class with an operator namely: `operator fun invoke(init: Robot.() -> Unit)`; however, this was done statically inside the class.

To complete this, I need to figure out, how to make an extension, made inside a method being accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I hoped there is a more elegant solution, but I could not find one.

First things first:
You don't need to pass a function. An invokable class suffices. An instance is callable when its class implements the operator "invoke". E.g.:

```
open class Extension {

   operator fun invoke() { /* ... */ }  

}
```

To configure the extension via a (script-) lambda, you'll need to the extend the invoke function to accept a lambda:

```
open class Extension {

   operator fun invoke(init: Extension.() -> Unit) {
     init(this)
   }  

}
```

---

However, the premise of this question was that the extensions do not implement the operator themselves. Instead, I wanted to add them. Defining an extension method would not work as it subject to scope.

This can be avoided by the defining the extension method inside the script:

```
type: Class<T>;

val code = """
    operator fun ${type.name}.invoke(init: ${type.name}.() -> Unit) {
        init(this)
    }
""".trimIndent()

scriptEngine.eval(code)
```